# Activity gets killed but saved bundle is not received in onCreate

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, oncreate

I have an application that works without fragments.
I modified an activity to use fragments.
The problem is that now when the activity goes in background and then in foreground again the onCreate is called: it looks like the activity gets killed to save memory or for another reason.

I tried to save a bundle in onSaveInstanceState  but when the activity is opened again I receive a null bundle in the onCreate and no call to onRestoreInstanceState (I checked that I receive a call to onSaveInstanceState when going in background).

Any clue?

thanks

Comment: I found the same beaviour with SDK 2.3 (SonyEricsson Xperia) and 3.0 (Motorola Xoom).

Comment: did you find the reason (or even a solution) for this behaviour in the meantime? I'm facing the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I recently updated my first application to use Fragments. I create the bundle in onSaveInstanceState and then I retrieve the bundle in onActivityCreated. Both methods are in the Fragment derived class! Maybe you're creating the bundle in the Fragment and then trying to retrieve it in the Activity?